# An undirected finite (simple) graph $G=(V,E)$ has a cycle, if $\forall_{v \in V}:\deg(v) = 2$ and $\#V \ge 3$

Tags: graph-theory, induction

Prove by complete induction over $\ell = \#V$: An undirected finite (simple) graph $G=(V,E)$ has a cycle, if $\forall_{v \in V}:\deg(v) = 2$ and $\#V \ge 3$.

**Basis**: Show that the statement holds for $\ell=3$. This can be done as follows. There is only one simple graph $G=(\{v_0,v_1,v_2\},\{\{v_0,v_1\},\{v_1,v_2\},\{v_2,v_0\}\})$ with $\deg(v) = 2$ for all $v \in V$ which has a cycle.

**Inductive step**: Show that if the statement holds for $\ell$, then the statement holds for $\ell + 1$. ...

My Problem is, I don't know how to make the inductive step. I know there is a prove by (i) taking any $v_0 \in V$ and then (ii) taking one of its two successors $v_1,v_2$ and repeat as long as I must reach a node $v_{\ell+1}=v_0$ because $\#V<\infty$. But I'm (a) not sure if this is the right choice for a complete induction and (b) I really don't know how to do this formally correct by complete induction.

**EDIT** I forgot to mention that this has to be done by complete induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the statement holds for $\ell$.

Now consider a 2-regular graph $G$ with $\ell+1$ vertices, pick one of its vertices, $v_1$ and its $2$ neighbors $v_0$ and $v_2$, then erase $v_1$ and connect $v_0$ to $v_2$ to obtain a $2$-regular graph $G'$ with $\ell$ vertices.

In fact, for this to work in general, we need a bit stronger inductive hypothesis: namely that *for any node* $v_1$ there is a cycle containing it.

Comment: Is it really that simple? These proves are scary :D ...

Comment: I've forgot to mention that a complete induction is required. Please excuse my mistake. Would your answer be still valid?

Comment: What do you mean by complete induction?

Comment: I thought there is a difference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction. I'm German and a little bit confused about the variants and the right translation.